# How to shift array elements 2 times to the right by two values in C?

Tags: c, logic

I have an array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` and I need to get `[__, __, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` where I can put my new elements in the blank spaces. I tried to do it in a standard way:

```
int temp1 = arr[len - 1];
int temp2 = arr[len - 2];

for (int i = len - 1; i > 1; i -= 2) {
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    arr[i - 1] = arr[i - 2];
}

arr[0] = temp1;
arr[1] = temp2;
```

but it seems to do nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only moving elements by one space, not by two. Take a look at the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
  {
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
  int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);

  printf("len = %d\n", len);

  int temp1 = arr[len - 1];
  int temp2 = arr[len - 2];

  printf("temp1 = %d\n", temp1);
  printf("temp2 = %d\n", temp2);

  for(int i = len-1 ; i > 1 ; --i)
    {
    printf("Moving arr[%d] to arr[%d]\n", i-2, i);
    arr[i] = arr[i-2];
    }

  arr[0] = temp1;
  arr[1] = temp2;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; ++i)
    printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
  }
```

[onlinegdb here](https://onlinegdb.com/Hy8lZp65L)

### EDIT

And if you'd rather do away with the loop and just copy the memory in one shot you can use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
  {
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
  int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);

  printf("len = %d\n", len);

  int temp1 = arr[len - 1];
  int temp2 = arr[len - 2];

  printf("temp1 = %d\n", temp1);
  printf("temp2 = %d\n", temp2);

  memmove(((int *)arr)+2, arr, (len-2)*sizeof(int));

  arr[0] = temp1;
  arr[1] = temp2;

  for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; ++i)
    printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
  }
```

Note here that I've used `memmove` instead of `memcpy` because the source and destination buffers overlap. `memmove` handles this correctly, while `memcpy` is not required to do so.

[onlinegdb here](https://onlinegdb.com/HJRDmTTcU)

Comment: This is, indeed, exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in the second example [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] outputs  [ _ _ 0, 3, 4, 5].

Comment: @tomashauser: I don't get that result. When I [run it at onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/SkUQAe0cI) with inputs of `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` it outputs `5, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3`. Did you perhaps replace `memmove` with `memcpy`? I would not be surprised if `memcpy` produces an incorrect result as `memcpy` may not handle the overlapped move correctly. What compiler and runtime are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that code rewrite right this way

```
int arr[8] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };

for( int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ ){
    arr[7-i] = arr[7-i-1];
}
for( int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ ){
    arr[7-i] = arr[7-i-1];
}


//here, arr[8] = { 1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6 }
//so, you can put new two elements in arr[0], arr[1]
```

Answer (score -2):

the below might be useful for you,

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <memory>

    int main()
    {
      int temp1[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
      int temp2[10] = { 0 }; // to avoid garbage values in 0 & 1 positions or you may find a place holder to indicate empty

      memcpy(&temp2[2], temp1, sizeof(temp1));

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
       printf("%d ", temp2[i]);

    }
```

Comment: Question is tagged for C, not C++.

Comment: I justed C++ for output, that is the reason your guys downvoted.

Comment: @tomashauser I have used the concept (memcpy) which is purely C only

Comment: `memcpy` doesn't (or at least isn't *required* to) handle overlapped moves properly.